# Почему я не могу использовать Edit&Continue режим в моем приложение на C#?

Tags: web-apps, visual-studio, c#

На фирме, где я работаю, написано веб-приложение на C#. Возникает ситуация, когда надо изменить что-то в cs файле, но для этого требуется перезагрузка Debug сессии. Когда же меняю aspx файл, то перезагружать ничего не надо.

Программа пишется в среде VS2010. Что может быть причиной, что режим Edit&Continue не работает для cs файлов и как можно обойти это ограничение?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите настройки студии: Options->Debugging->Edit and Continue. Должна стоять галочка: "Enable Edit and Continue"

Answer (score 0):

Ну, я думаю, что файл кода вызывается вначале (Load_Page), поэтому при его изменении, разумеется, нужна перекомпиляция, а файл разметки не компилируется, а компонуется вместе с ресурсами, то есть он не вызывается в постоянном цикле, а только при отправке страницы на сервер, значит, между отправками мы можем как угодно его изменять. Код приложения (cs-файл) выполняется на сервере в непрерывном потоке (ждёт запросов), поэтому любое изменение кода для него критично. Надеюсь, вы что-нибудь поймёте из этого потока мыслей.